# Double? will trim decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application , and i have the following variable for storing memory info in GB:-

```
  public double? TotalMemoryGB2 { set; get; }
```

and the following method to convert byte to GB:-

```
if (serverjoin.Resource.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo != null)
            {

                serverjoin.Resource.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TotalMemoryGB2 = (serverjoin.Resource.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
                s
            }
```

now i idea of the above method is that the `TOTALMEMORY` is stored is bytes and i want to convert the value from byte to GB by doing the following:-

```
(serverjoin.Resource.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

but now if the i have the TOTALMEMEORY value as `1610612736` so instead of getting 1.5 inside the TotalMemoryGB2 i will get 1 ? can anyone adivce on this

Comment: Add a .0 to any 1024. You're doing an integer division.

Comment: ...or *mark* `1024` as being `double`: `1024d * 1024d * 1024d` (`d` suffix)

Comment: `d` suffix is more readable